# Gwt + Maven + Idea, configuration and running

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I've created gwt project using maven plugin:

```
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1 -DgroupId=com.savdev.BasicGwtProject -DartifactId=BasicGwtProject -Dversion=1.0 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:generate
```

In project settings I've added the GWT facet. When I set path to GWT - to the GWT installed directory (gwt-2.5.1 version), the warning has appeared:

Path is not valid GWT installation: class 'com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler' not found in jar:...gwt-dev.jar

Can I fix it? IDEA offers to download GWT, but it's already downloaded and it's the last version. Maybe IDEA does not still support the last GWT version?

Second problem, 
I've run: maven install. The output is:

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running junit.framework.TestSuite@2ad1e832
[INFO] Please navigate your browser to this URL:
[INFO] http://169.254.56.62:55728/com.savdev.BasicGwtProject.gwtBasicModuleJUnit.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=169.254.56.62:55724
```

I've navigated it, but browser did not respond anything. (By the way I have `GWT developer plugin` installed). What actually is it supposed to do here?

The last issue I'd like to discover also is about running the application.
I've configured in `Project/Edit configuration/GWT configuration` as described [here](http://antonkirillov.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/creating-and-running-gwt-project-using-maven-and-intellij-idea-10/) except I left start page option clear.

Then I ran the configuration in IDEA. Now I can see the output:

```
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.junit.server.JUnitHostImpl' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/sav/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.1/gwt-user-2.5.1.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/D:/DevSoft/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
Dev Mode initialized
```

I'm not sure at the moment what are these warnings about, but, I've tried to visit page:

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

I can see only WEB-INF and the folder named as my module name - `'gwtBasicModule'`.
I look at web.xml and found:

```
<!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>gwtBasicModule.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Also a generated gwtBasicModule.html file exists. Why I cannot see it when I visit `http://localhost:8888/` page? How can I correctly run application both via IDEA and Maven gwt plugin?

Comment: Please mention which IDEA edition you are using version/community edition/licensed etc

Comment: have the same issue with IDEA 12.0.1 buid #IU-123.94

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your [test mode](http://mojohaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/test-mojo.html#mode)